# Put into clipboard some hyperlink (VBA)

Tags: vba, hyperlink, clipboard, ms-project

I'm writing some macro for MS Project. I have some URL string and string with text to display. 
I created hyperlink like:

```
    wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    urlString, SubAddress:= _
    "", TextToDisplay:= _
    displayText
```

So, how can I put this link into clipboard?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192913.aspx

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it for hyperlinks. Can you help me?

Comment: In addition, the method description and examples are only for strings.

Comment: Where do you want to be able to paste the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work in MS Project with added MS Word Object Library

```
Dim hLink As Object
Dim wd As Object
Dim appWd As Word.Application
Dim strUrl, strName

Set strUrl = "mysite.com"
Set strName = "My hypelink to mysite.com"

'Create temp Word doc

Set appWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = appWd.Documents.Add

Set hLink = wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=wdDoc.Range, _
    Address:=strUrl, _
    SubAddress:="", _
    ScreenTip:="", _
    TextToDisplay:=strName)

'text format
hLink.Range.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
hLink.Range.Font.Size = 10
hLink.Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

hLink.Range.Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim wdDoc, h, urlString, displayText

    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

    urlString = "http://google.com"
    displayText = "google"

    Set h = wdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
                    Address:=urlString, SubAddress:="", _
                    TextToDisplay:=displayText)

    h.Range.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: it's not absolutely correctly works. I tried this macro in the MS Word, there it works, but when I try to use it in the MS Project I began to receive an error "Type mismatch" for the line "Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument" . I added a reference to the MS Word Object Library and this error disappeared, but appeared another error "ActiveX component can't create object 429". How can I fix it?